# Aggregation within a certain time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a list of the 2 rating hotels in the UK that have increased their rating by at least 3 points from the beginning.

```
Month       | Hotel | Rating | Region |
---------------------------------------
01-Jan-19   | A     | 1      |  US    |
01-Feb-19   | B     | 2      |  UK    |
01-Mar-19   | C     | 3      |  EU    |
01-Apr-19   | A     | 1      |  US    |
01-May-19   | B     | 4      |  UK    |
01-Jun-19   | C     | 3      |  EU    |
01-Jul-19   | A     | 1      |  US    |
01-Aug-19   | B     | 5      |  UK    |
01-Sep-19   | C     | 4      |  EU    |
```

Like this, the query must produce Hotel **B** only.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Your expected output ?

Comment: You "month" is not being stored as a string.  Please tell me that it is really a date/time column.

Comment: Carra, I need to create a list of the 2 rating hotels in the UK that have increased their rating by at least 3 points from the beginning.

Comment: xXx, the query must produce Hotel B only.

Comment: Gordon, I edited it. it's a date/time column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This also works

I have tried it

```
Select "Hotel"

From T

Where "Region" = 'UK'

Group by "Hotel"
                Having 
                        Min ("Rating") = 2
                And 
                        Max ("Rating") >= 5
```

The Link to test:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6TVgrC5WRjqdyPwdGSvWGN/8

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the first and last entries.  One method uses conditional aggregation.  I am going to assume that `month` is really a date or number and not a string:

```
select t.hotel
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by hotel order by month asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by hotel order by month desc) as seqnum_desc
     from t
    ) t
group by t.hotel
having max(rating) filter (where seqnum_asc = 1) >= max(rating) filter (where seqnum_desc = 1) + 3;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. Always, thanks a lot for your help. But I need to specify the region, too. (Only UK). I think I'll need to use WHERE clause before the GROUP BY clause, right?

Comment: @Nash . . . Add `where region = 'UK'` to the subquery.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot Gordon for your help.